# How to reference external files with JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

Here is the error I am getting when JSON.net is trying to read my JSON schema ( `return JsonSchema.Read(new JsonTextReader(reader));` ):

```
2014-07-15 15:33:42.7011 [Fatal] Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException: Could not resolve schema reference 'data-result.json'.
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ResolveReferences(JsonSchema schema) in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Work
ing\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Schema\JsonSchemaBuilder.cs:line 139
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.ResolveReferences(JsonSchema schema) in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Work
ing\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Schema\JsonSchemaBuilder.cs:line 179
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchemaBuilder.Read(JsonReader reader) in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsof
t.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Schema\JsonSchemaBuilder.cs:line 85
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Read(JsonReader reader, JsonSchemaResolver resolver) in c:\Development\Releases\
Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Schema\JsonSchema.cs:line 280
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema.Read(JsonReader reader) in c:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Newtonsoft.Json\
Src\Newtonsoft.Json\Schema\JsonSchema.cs:line 266
   at ThinkBinary.SchemaToPoco.Core.JsonSchemaToCodeUnit.LoadSchema(String file) in c:\Users\SLiu\Projects\json-schema-t
o-poco\Source\ThinkBinary.SchemaToPoco.Core\JsonSchemaToCodeUnit.cs:line 70
   at ThinkBinary.SchemaToPoco.Core.JsonSchemaToCodeUnit..ctor(String schemaDocument, String requestedNamespace) in c:\U
sers\SLiu\Projects\json-schema-to-poco\Source\ThinkBinary.SchemaToPoco.Core\JsonSchemaToCodeUnit.cs:line 19
   at ThinkBinary.SchemaToPoco.Console.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\SLiu\Projects\json-schema-to-poco\Source\
ThinkBinary.SchemaToPoco.Console\Program.cs:line 38
```

My JSON schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#",
  "title": "DataSet",
  "description": "A result set and description of measures and values",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "results": {
      "$ref": "data-result.json"
    },
    "dimensions": {
      "type": "array",
      "description": "An array of data dimensions included in a result set",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "data-dimension.json"
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    },
    "measure": {
      "$ref": "data-measure.json",
      "description": "single measure represented in this data set."
    }
  },
}
```

My problem is that I have this JSON schema with this reference to an external file, `data-result.json`, but JSON.net does not yet know it exists. Is there some sort of fix for this? One idea I have is to skim through the schema, and if there are any references to external files, to parse those with a common [`JsonSchemaResolver`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/RefJsonSchemaResolver.htm). I'd have to add IDs as appropriate, since it looks like `$ref` likes to match by the ID, even though over at json-schema.org, there are clear examples of `$ref` being used with [file names](http://json-schema.org/example2.html). I'd like to know if there is a better way that JSON.net natively supports referencing external schemas.

The source code is hosted on [Github](https://github.com/sbl03/json-schema-to-poco), if it helps. I have tested with the `$ref` field removed, and it compiles successfully.

Answer (score 2):

**[Json.NET Schema](http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema)** has much improved support for resolving external references.

Read more here: http://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/LoadingSchemas.htm

Answer (score 1):

> One idea I have is to skim through the schema, and if there are any references to external files, to parse those with a common `JsonSchemaResolver`

Yes, you need to know which schemas your schema depends on, parse those first and add them to a `JsonSchemaResolver`. The schemas will be resolved using their IDs.

Here's an example (using draft-03 syntax):

```
var baseSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(@"
{
  ""$schema"": ""http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#"",
  ""id"": ""http://mycompany/base-schema#"",
  ""type"": ""object"",

  ""properties"": {
    ""firstName"": { ""type"": ""string"", ""required"": true}
  }
}
");

var resolver = new JsonSchemaResolver
    {
        LoadedSchemas = {baseSchema}
    };

var derivedSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(@"
{
  ""$schema"": ""http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema#"",
  ""id"": ""http://mycompany/derived-schema#"",
  ""type"": ""object"",

  ""extends"":{ ""$ref"": ""http://mycompany/base-schema#""},

  ""properties"": {
    ""lastName"": { ""type"": ""string"", ""required"": true}
  }
}
", resolver);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g1nFew

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you have relative URI's in those `$ref` items, but no `id` properties to establish a base URI.   You may be able to resolve your problem by adding `id="<absolute-url>"`in the outermost context establishing where those external files can be retrieved from.

See section 7 of http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html

P.S.  In your `measure` item, I notice you have both a `$ref` and `description` values.   The json-reference internet draft says *Any members other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be ignored.*   It probably doesn't do any harm, but could be surprising if someone was to expect that value to override the description in the external file.

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question, but I am pretty sure the answer is that JSON.net does not resolve references - you need to do it yourself. It WILL resolve `$ref` from the `id` attribute, which is the workaround I mentioned and implemented. I noticed in the code for [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo) that they resolved the references themselves, so I created a [similar utility for C#](https://github.com/cvent/json-schema-2-poco).