# Deserialize multiple json files

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I try to use **Newtonsoft.json** in order to deserialize an assemble of json files.
I have my C# classes corresponding to the schema that working great.
If i put all my json files in one, it deserializes without any problems, but i want to have some readable files. To do that, i have separated them in multiple files.

When i do that, even with a link between them, **Newtonsoft.json** can't create a complete model with the corresponding schema.

For example, i have the below C# classes in Application and `DataModel` like below:

```
class Application
{
    [JsonProperty("dataModel", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DataModel dataModel { get; set; }
}

class DataModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.Always)]
    public String id { get; set; }
}
```

and my json to deserialize is :

- application.json:

  ```
  {
    "dataModel": {"$ref":"data.json"}
  }
  ```
- data.json:

  ```
  {
    "$id": "dataModel",
    "id": "dataModel",
  }
  ```

I execute the code line to deserialize :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(File.ReadAllText(@"application.json"),
   new JsonSerializerSettings {
   PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

After that i just check if my Application have a `DataModel`, but i get an exception that tell me that **`DataModel` is null**.

I don't know if the problem is because **Newtonsoft** can't make the link between simple json file or if it's something else.
A little bit of help will be welcome :-)

Comment: What actually happens when you try it?

Comment: Newtonsoft can't deserialize your json file because it's not valid json https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Specifically, the JSON of the second file is invalid due to the extra comma at the end of the second `"dataModel"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference external files with JSON.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768479/how-to-reference-external-files-with-json-net)

Comment: @Abion47 the dataModel property is null, I removed the extra comma and the same result

Comment: @SirRufo The question is for schema, I'm not using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out a proper solution to your problem. In the meantime, though, perhaps you can do a workaround in the form of a custom converter.

Your classes:

```
class Application
{
    public DataModel dataModel { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(DataModelConverter))]
class DataModel
{
    public String id { get; set; }
}
```

DataModelConverter.cs

```
class DataModelConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(DataModel);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jobj = JObject.Load(reader);

        if (jobj["$ref"] != null)
        {
            string path = jobj["$ref"].Value<string>();
            string json = File.ReadAllText(path);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataModel>(json);
        }

        var model = new DataModel
        {
            id = jobj.Value<string>("id")
        };

        return model;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var model = value as DataModel;

        string path = "data.json";
        string json = $"{{\r\n\t\"$id\" : \"{model.id}\",\r\n\t\"id\" : \"{model.id}\"\r\n}}";
        File.WriteAllText(path, json);

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("$ref");
        serializer.Serialize(writer, path);
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's simple. all you need is a wrapper class. something like this:

```
class Wrapper
{
    class Application
    {
        [JsonProperty("dataModel", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public DataModel dataModel { get; set; }
    }

    class DataModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("id", Required = Required.Always)]
        public String id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

then try this:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("{"+File.ReadAllText(@"application.json")+"}",
   new JsonSerializerSettings {
   PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
   ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

Comment: When i try your solution, I get and exception : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : 'Invalid property identifier character: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Answer (score 0):

After merging the files in a single object, now the references works. So I think that it's not possible to resolve references with JsonConvert.